# Azure openai The API deployment for this resource does not exist

Tags: azure, openai-api, azure-openai, gpt-4

I am making sequential calls to Azure OpenAI GPT-4 from a python code. The token size of each call is approx 5000 tokens (inclusing input, prompt and output). The first call goes good. But the API is failing everytime on the 2nd request throwing the below error:

```
"The API deployment for this resource does not exist. If you created the deployment within the last 5 minutes,"
```

I tried to put a sleep command of till 60s before hitting the API, since I know that there is a limit to number of tokens per minute for GPT4. But still throwing the same issue in every 2nd call.
Any suggestions will be very helpful.

Comment: Hard to say without any implementation details. Failing on the 2nd try with a "deployment not found" error is really strange, but we cannot help you more on that

Answer (score 0):

I dealt with the same issue, turns out my Azure resource didn't have GPT4 as a model deployment. Here's how I found out which I had access to.

[image]

[image]